# Serving a PHP script with parameters and a Django based configuration on Apache

Tags: php, django, apache, .htaccess

I have the following setup for my Django based website:

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.4>

   DocumentRoot "/home/joel/www"
   <Directory "/home/joel/www">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   </Directory>

   WSGIScriptAlias / "/home/joel/www/app.wsgi"

   Alias /book /php/book.php?id=1

   ServerName mysite.local
</VirtualHost>
```

I would like to serve a PHP script when someone access `mysite.local/book` which is located at `/php/book.php`. This works fine if I don't want to send parameters to the script (i.e. `Alias /book /php/book.php`). However, when i try to send a parameter such as `id=1`it fails. How can I achieve this redirection with the configuration file above?

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use alias, but mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^book$ /php/book.php?id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use alias, but mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^book$ /php/book.php?id=1
```

Wrong regular expression `^book$` for `/book` string. Should be `^/book$`.